# Minimum initial velocity to avoid collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, potential-energy

I'm having problem with the solution of this question:

> Two material points with mass $m$ move along a horizontal axis subjected only to Newton's gravitational force law. At the instant $t_0=0$, one of the points is located at position $x=1$ with velocity $v_0>0$, while the other point is at position $x=-1$ with velocity $-v_0$. Assume that all the given data is in the International System of Units (SI) and denote $G$ as the gravitational constant. What is the minimum value of $v_0$ for these points to not collide at some instant $t_1>0$?

The solution I was given is this:

$$E_k+U_g\ge 0$$

Where $E_k$ and $U_g$ denote the kinetic energy and $U_g$ the gravitational potential energy. Then:

$$\frac{m(v_0)^2}{2}+\frac{m(-v_0)^2}{2}-\frac{Gmm}{2}=0$$

And then solve for $v_0$ to find the minimum velocity.

Now, this is not the "official" solution by any means, but it does get the correct answer.

I'm having problems understanding the first step:

- It does make sense that the potential energy should be "stronger" than the kinetic energy of the particle moving away for the collision to happen. But this is not that clear for me. Could this be stated in more scientific terms?
- Also, why use the kinetic energy of both particles but the potential energy of a single one?

My thinking is that the collision is going to happen if at some point $v$ changes signal. We would need to sort of integrate the acceleration to find an expression for $v$, because the acceleration is not constant, and then solve for $v_0$. But I'm newbie and this seems to be overkill compared to the proposed solution. I'm just having a hard time making sense of the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by considering the two masses before they are accelerated to their minimum velocity, so they only have potential energy
$$E = U = -\frac{Gm^2}{r_0},$$
where $r_0=2.$ Why is this value negative? We define $U$ to be zero when the masses are infinitely far apart, and we define potential energy to decrease when masses move in the same direction as the forces that create the potential energy. Potential energy goes down when masses fall down. Setting $U(\infty) = 0$ is a mathematical convenience; it's just as valid to set it to zero at the surface of the Earth when the problem calls for it ($U = mgh,$ for example).

In order to stop the masses from ever colliding, we have to get them to a configuration where they no longer attract each other. Gravity is always attractive at a finite distance, so the only configuration is an infinite distance apart. The potential energy at infinite distance is zero. The amount of work required to change configurations is
$$\Delta U = 0 - \left(-\frac{Gm^2}{r_0}\right) = \frac{Gm^2}{r_0}.$$
One way to provide this energy is to give the masses sufficient kinetic energy.
$$K > \Delta U$$
$$\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 \geq \frac{Gm^2}{r_0}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 - \frac{Gm^2}{r_0} \geq 0$$
This is the same solution as yours once you set $m_1 = m_2 = m$ and $v_1 = -v_2 = v_0.$ As it turns out, you can distribute the initial kinetic energy between the masses however you want, as long as the total energy is at least zero.

Answer (score 1):

> - Also, why use the kinetic energy of both particles but the potential energy of a single one?

There is only one gravitational interaction between the two particles. This is a general effect: potential energies need to be taken as shared between stuff, and so it is important to not over-count their contributions to the total energy budget.

> - It does make sense that the potential energy should be "stronger" than the kinetic energy of the particle moving away for the collision to happen. But this is not that clear for me. Could this be stated in more scientific terms?

Total energy is conserved. By the symmetry of the problem, it is clear that $x_2=-x_1$ and $v_2=-v_1\equiv-v$ for this system, for all time. If there is a turning point for the particles, then, it should be the case that $v=0$ for some finite time. But that means the kinetic energy contributions would be zero, and if the particles have not reached infinitely far apart at that time, then the gravitational potential energy contribution would mean that the total energy $<0.$ It is thus clear that, as long as the total energy $\geqslant0,$ then you will get no more collision.

i.e. the answer key already gave you a perfectly good answer.